# Installing an application into a docker containers through SSH

Tags: docker, ssh

To give the background, I have a deployment workflow which concurrently downloads and installs an application into multiple systems/servers. To test this workflow, I need to verify the concurrent deployment on 500 systems. I am not in a position to create 500 VMs to test this. I took the approach of Docker containers to test this workflow. Now the challenge is if I start a container with public/static IP address and install ssh inside the container, then I can login to this container via ssh. But I cannot start aother container with same configuration because port 22 is already used by container #1 on the host and I cannot give different ports because my deployment workflow internally uses only port 22.

I think using port forwarding/NAT this can be achieved, may be whenever a request comes to IP#1, then use the port 22 and when ever a request comes to IP#2 then use the port #27. But I am not sure if this is possible.

Any pointers on this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

First, docker maps container ports to different host ports -- launch containers with -p.

```
docker run mycontainer -p 10001:22
docker run mycontainer -p 10002:22
docker run mycontainer -p 10003:22
etc.
```

From the [docker run reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/):

> -p=[] : Publish a container᾿s port or a range of ports to the host.

**Edit:** I think I misread your use of ssh.

Does the deployment workflow connect to each container via ssh (push) or is it contacted(pull)? If push, just push out to 500 clients, e.g. :10001 through :10501. If pull, all clients will be calling on 22 anyway.